# Azure DevOps agent not picking up yml based jobs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

So I'm using Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1 and self-hosted agents on Linux. I'm desperately trying to get my agent to pick up my jobs but it won't. It's not busy, no capability issues (test pipeline with only a single "hello world"-style inline script), no permission issues (not that I can see). The diagnostic log looks fine, no connection issues as far as I can tell.
Always this message comes out:

**The agent request is not running because all potential agents are running other requests. Current position in queue: 1**

**No agents in pool Default are currently able to service this request.**

The funny thing is I've just discovered that my agent is picking up non-yaml jobs created in the classic editor. Why is that??? Anybody ever encountered this issue before??? Is there somewhere hidden in the guts of the Server a checkbox that must be ticked in order to run yaml pipelines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out all I had to do was to update my Linux agents from the version 2.188 to the latest version 2.193. The odd thing is I have an identical server in another network where everything worked just fine with the old agent version.

Comment: This worked for me too, but in a different way: I had to update the agent version from 2.217.2/2.210.1 to the most up to date version 3.225.2.
This might be dependent on the installed Version of Azure Devops Server and there might be a corelation between DevOps Server and Agent Service versions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a self hosted agent within a YAML job . You can refer to the below example

```
- job: Name_of_job
  displayName: Display name
  pool:
      name: '<Name of the POOL>'
```

Comment: I'm way past that stage where I don't know how to set up a yaml pipeline, thanks anyway