# My Azure devOps Pipeline doesn't seem to see the Self-Hosted Agent

Tags: azure-devops

I am running a Azure DevOps pipeline using a Self-Hosted Agent
[image]

As we see above the Self-Hosted Agent on my PC is up and running and visible from my DevOps Organization.
However, every time I run the pipeline I get the error below:
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: can you try to update the agent to e.g. version `2.211.1`? ive seen similar behaviour with `2.204.0` but not with the newer version (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69594216/14141116)

Answer (score 0):

> My Azure devOps Pipeline doesn't seem to see the Self-Hosted Agent

According to the error message:

[image]

It seeems you are still using the hosted agent.

So, please try to double check your pipeline configuration about the Agent pool, make sure it using the private agent pool **Default**:

[image]

And if it already set as Default, then please check Agent pool
under Agent job:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are still using Default Agent for pipeline job running so just check the agent pool name if it's Default than replace it with your self hosted agent name.

if you still face the error that you mentioned, than you need to fill "Azure DevOps Parallelism Request" form.

the URL for that form is given at the end of your error message.

it will take approximate 2-3 business days to activate.

Answer (score 0):

I had the following message and solved the issue by correting the Security under agent pool changed the user permission from `Reader` to `Administrator`

in the below link [About security roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-security-roles?view=azure-devops)